# GWT Highcharts legend.setOption("useHTML", true) disables clicking on legend item

Tags: highcharts, gwt-highcharts

in the GWT wrapper for highcharts, I want to customize my legend entries and still be able to click on them and make them hidden. I create a legend and do `legend.setOption("useHTML", true)` and then modify `.highcharts-legend-item span` some CSS (mainly making sure it can be aligned to the right) but this disables clickablity on the legend item (i can still click on the legend icon to hide the series)

Comment: Have you the newest highcharts ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using an outdated version of highcharts.js. This was a known issue in 2.3.2 and fixed in 2.3.5

Comment: im a little concerned about the compatability with the most recent GWT wrapper by moxie and the most recent version of highcharts